# Changing Data to other Activity

Tags: android

I'm making a game wich will allow user to select different types, in MainActivity will have a Alert Dialog for user to select .
there are 2 element (speed_1 and speed_2 )which are number that will affect the difficulty in GameActivity

I want to make it like if the user check "Easy" in the Alert Dialog , speed_1 and speed_2 will change to 1(in GameActivity)

if the user check "difficult" in the Alert Dialog , speed_1 and speed_2 will change to 3(in GameActivity)

Thank you !

```
void generateLevelListDialog() {
    // Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Specify the list in the dialog using the array
    builder.setTitle("Difficulty").setItems(R.array.levels_array,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                // Chain together various setter methods to set the list
                // items
                // The index of the item selected is passed by the parameter
                // which
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //switch to game activity
                    Intent gameIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                    //change ball speed and racket length
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:

                            break;

                        case 1:
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    //start activity
                    startActivity(gameIntent);

                }
            });
    //create and show list dialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have two options here:

1) Save selected value to the preferences and read it later in the `GameActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

write in `MainActivity`

```
preferences.edit().putInt("speed_1", speed_1).apply();
```

read in `GameActivity`

```
int speed_1 = preferences.getInt("speed_1", 0);
```

As a bonus next time user plays your game it will use previously selected difficulty level.

2) Pass difficulty level value (speed_1..speed_3) to the `GameActivity` via `gameIntent` using extras:

write in `MainActivity`

```
Intent gameIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
gameIntent.putExtra("speed_1", speed_1);
```

read in `GameActivity`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String speed_1 = extras.getInt("speed_1");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , when run the app there is no error , but in that app when I chick "Easy" ,The game clashed , do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Check logcat/output windows in your IDE, it should display an exception stacktrace which would give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value with Intent like below

```
int level;

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
          switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        level = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        level = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        level = 3;
                        break;
                    default:
                        level = 1;      // Default Value
                        break;
                }

intent.putExtra("DIFFICULTY_LEVEL", level);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in GameActivity.java, you can simply get the value like below

```
int level = getIntent().getIntExtra()("DIFFICULTY_LEVEL", 1); // where '1' is default value
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply , I am trying to apply it to my code , but om Game activity "()("DIFFICULTY_LEVEL", 1);"  got a Red underlined and it said " excepted token " , what should I do ? Thank you

Comment: That Problem solved , but when run the app there is no error , but in that app when I chick "Easy" The game clashed , do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: It'll be helpful that you Post the exception/error from the Logcat that you are facing.